# cocos2d-x crashes during visit() calls

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I have cocos2d-x app crashing time after time. Crash happens in random cases, even in idle state — I can leave app in simulator and after 2-5 minutes it may crash with no user interaction. 
The sad thing — it crashed in production, too. I use Crittercism crash reporting SDK and it shows the same stack.
More, I tried cocos2d-x samples bundled with cocos SDK, they crash the same way.
Here I included some screenshots to show up the stacks:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5480488/cocos2dxcrash1.png
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5480488/cocos2dxcrash2.png

+cocos2dxcrash3.png

And yes, it affects (almost?) all available versions of Cocos and iOS. Currently it crashes in latest cocos2d-x and iOS 6.1.3.

SOS, please!

Comment: It looks like memory is being corrupted *somewhere*.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are running your app on a simulator.
Running on a device will solve it. :P
Thought I don't know the exact reason. I have met the same problem before.